# Unit Test or Integrate Test a specific folder in a bit bucket repo

Tags: continuous-integration, bitbucket, integration-testing, devops

How can I run a unit test / Integration test for a specific folder from a git repo hosted on Bit Bucket?

```
My repo/
|
|__ folder A
|   |__app.js
|   |__test.js
|
|__ folder B
    |__server.js
    |__test.js
```

I have made some changes in the folder A -> app.js file and uploaded so my pipeline should test only the folder A not both the folder(a & b) in the repo.

Please suggest me the possibility and reference document links.

Comment: This totally depends on what tool you use to run the tests

Comment: @Jonas Is there any tool to do integration testing of different module stays indifferent repository

Comment: Integration testing is what you do when it involves network requests. Here it sounds like you want to have a **contract** between modules. That is usually done with an **interface** in programming languages, e.g. https://blog.logrocket.com/interfaces-in-typescript-what-are-they-and-how-do-we-use-them-befbc69b38b3/

Comment: Integration testing does not necessarily require network requests. Could be testing of a 100% pure local application as well. Anyway, usually CI tests trigger with a new commit in your VCS and do not care what specific change was made. Also, the sense of your CI is to do a complete check for every change made. If you want to run only a subset of test, then do that manually during coding with your IDE or command line.